# jquery html from xml

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, dom

[demo](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zczlqywn1quk2kl/JDfaVs_iKb). see console

Lets assume scenes.xml is a list of sections

```
<sections>
  <section>
    <div...
  </section>
  ...
</sections>
```

and `preload` is a predefined hidden block.
I'm loading this xml with $.ajax (of course with dataType: "xml") and trying to get html:

```
$(xmlData).find("section").each(function() {
  console.log(preload.empty().append(this).html())
})
```

It works perfect anywhere except ie 7-10. it throws:

```
 DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)
 in jquery.js (1.7.2) on line 6497
```

PS Of course I can wrap each section with **CDATA** and use text() to obtain html. But I want to avoid this workaround because each section is valid xml or html

Answer (score 0):

extreme ugly workaround:

```
preload.empty()
if($.browser.msie) {
  if($.browser.version == "7.0" or $.browser.version == "8.0") {
    preload.append($(xmlData.xml).filter("section"))
  } else {
    preload.append($(xmlData.xml).find("section"))
  }
} else {
  preload.append($(xmlData).find("section"))
}
html = preload.html()
preload.empty().html(html)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `$.parseXML` if you're parsing XML.

Comment: please re-read question again. I'm using $.ajax with dataType: "xml" and it invokes parseXML automaticaly. if you dont understand question - please **do not close bugs at the bugtracker**